# SQL Server using ISNULL and getting back no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried both these queries and what I dont understand is why my first query returns '0' (when it should) but my second query returns nothing - its just blank

I understand the 1st query returns the total sum of the products that have the currencycode 'USD' and if it is not found it returns '0', and the second query should return 0 because there is no products with the currencycode 'USD'.

Is there something wrong with my second query?

```
select ISNULL(SUM(Cost), 0) as Amount from products where Currencycode = 'USD'
select ISNULL(COST,0) as amount FROM PRODUCTS where currencycode= 'USD'
```

Keeping in mind I have no NULL fields, so why does the first query return 0 and the second doesn't

Comment: Two types of query: Row based, Absolute aggregate. Absolute aggregate always returns 1 row, everything else returns one row per matching result. Your query where clause doesn't match any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is doing an aggregation of values with the SUM function and if there is no row the returned value is 0.
Your second query is returning a value for every occurrences that matches your WHERE clause, in your case if there is no row in the table, the query will simple not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

yes missl

because

```
 select ISNULL(COST,0) as amount FROM PRODUCTS where currencycode= 'USD'
```

query have no rows selected

but when we use aggregate functions it returns even null also in one row so your first query returns 0

but in second query no rows returns so it blanks

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns a scalar value because `SUM`  is an aggregation, you are calculating the sum of all costs with currencycode=USD.

The second query returns no rows because the `WHERE` excludes all rows:

```
select ISNULL(COST,0) as amount FROM PRODUCTS where currencycode= 'USD'
```

As you've mentioned that are no products with currency=USD.

If you instead want to know in each row the USD-Cost  this should work:

```
SELECT Usd_Cost = CASE WHEN  currencycode = 'USD' THEN Cost Else 0 END 
FROM PRODUCTS
```

Otherwise i have no idea what you expect the second query to return.

Answer (score 0):

First Query:

Summing the all cost values. So we don't have any Null value until entire columns is null

```
select ISNULL(SUM(Cost), 0) as Amount from products where Currencycode = 'USD'
```

Second Query:

There is no rollup. Directly if it is a null you will get or else No

```
select ISNULL(COST,0) as amount FROM PRODUCTS where currencycode= 'USD'
```